# LC3: Unexpected TRAP xCF instruction giving error

Tags: assembly, lc3

**CONTEXT:**

I'm writing a program where the user is requested to input a "1" or "2", that value's ASCII value is added by -49, and depending if the sum is 0 or 1, a string will be printed.

**CONFLICT:**

When I simulated my code, I noticed an odd instruction highlighted in the image below. I don't know where it came from, but when it is executed it gives me the error `A trap was executed with an illegal vector number.` Where did it come from, and how do I fix this?

Thank you!

[Simulation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRSd8.png)

**CODE:**

```
    .ORIG x3000

; INPUT REQUEST: Store input value into R0
START   TRAP x23

; FILL PROCESS: Put value -49 in address of FN. Load value in FN address (-49) into R4
    LD R4, FN
FN  .FILL #-49

; CASE CREATION: Add -49 (R4) to input value (R0)
    ADD R3, R0, R4

; BRANCHES: If R3 = 0, execute Case 1 Instruction. If R3 > 0 (specifically if R3 = 1), execute Case 2 Instruction
    BRz CAS1I
    BRp CAS2I

; BRANCH CASES:

; CASE 1 INSTRUCTION: Load Case 1 String into R1. Print string in R1. Jump to  START (input request).
CAS1I   LEA R1, CAS1S
    TRAP x22
    BRnzp START

; CASE 2 INSTRUCTION: Load Case 2 String into R2. Print string in R2. Jump to  START (input request).
CAS2I   LEA R2, CAS2S
    TRAP x22
    BRnzp START

; STRING STORAGE: Store input patterns in Case 1 String and Case 2 String
CAS1S   .STRINGZ "1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100"
CAS2S   .STRINGZ "1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100"

    .END
```

Comment: You put data in the middle of the code. The CPU interprets that `.FILL #-49` as an instruction and it happens to be a `TRAP`. Move it out of code path.

Comment: Oh that fixed it! Thank you very much. Why is `.FILL #-49` considered data?